# Got exception in MR_workingName method when using com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

Tags: magicalrecord

I create Core Data stack like this using MagicalRecord

```
MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Warn)
MagicalRecord.setDefaultModelNamed("myAPP.momd")
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed("myAPP")
```

then I add separated context to our persistent store for faster large imports

```
importContext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.MR_defaultStoreCoordinator())
```

And all is working fine until I change MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Warn to MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Verbose

In this case I start getting exception in Magical Record method MR_workingName while **com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1** is set. So this method calls the exception

```
CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:
```

in this string:

```
NSString *workingName = [[self userInfo] objectForKey:MagicalRecordContextWorkingName];
```

I never call MR_workingName method by myself from any thread. 
Is this behavior OK? Or may be my stack is the reason I got this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem!